# Как увеличить скорость сборки Gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Я разрабатываю для Android. Поскольку я заметил, что скорость сборки Gradle очень медленная, то хотел бы узнать:

Как повысить скорость сборки Gradle?
Как настроить Android Studio?

Я использую Gradle версии 3.3.

Answer (score 6):

Чтобы увеличить скорость сборки Gradle, я использую следующие настройки:

1 - Выберите File > Settings > Gradle > и отредактируйте, как показано ниже:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> - выберите вариант `Offline work` и нажмите `ОК`.

---

2 - Выберите File > Settings > Compiler > и отредактируйте, как показано ниже:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> - Выберите четыре параметра выше "Compile, Make, Sync, Configure" и поместите в `Command-line Options: --offline` и нажмите «ОК».

---

3 - Теперь измените следующий скрипт **build.gradle (Module: app)** - добавьте **dexOptions**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
       ...
        }

        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    }
```

Добавить этот раздел:

```
    dexOptions {
                    javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
}
```

---

4 - Теперь измените следующий сценарий **gradle.properties (Свойства проекта)**:

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true


# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
```

Добавить этот раздел:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

Если там есть предупреждение, нажмите `Try Again ...` или `Sync Now` и посмотрите результат.

---

**Совет:** Если ваша Android Studio заходит слишком долго, чтобы начать, я также рекомендую посмотреть [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37632314/how-to-increase-memory-ide-android-studio/), как увеличить память IDE.

---

Надеюсь, я помог. Со мной это сработало, **Gradle** работает намного быстрее.

Большое спасибо